# PHP the right way to use constants with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I have a PHP library on packagist.org, which uses some constants, changing from project to project.

I'm trying to use constants like that:

- Constants stores in **conf.php** in composer libriary
- After **composer init username/mylib** command, I making a copy from **/vendor/username/mylib/conf.php** to local **/conf.php** and use it for current project config

for project1, in **/conf.php**

```
define("HOST", "host1.com");
```

project2, in **/conf.php**

```
define("HOST", "host2.com");
```

But it looks like a wrong way.

What is right way to use constants with composer libraries ?

Comment: Just a note, the *right* way can be classed as subjective.

Comment: One way would be to create instances of your class with a config array (kinda like Guzzle and many more do it). IMO you should never have any changes that need to be made in composer plugins. It makes updating them absolute hell.

Comment: @h2ooooooo, good point, but I still have to store config somewhere, and provide config instuctions

Comment: @h2ooooooo that's exactly how I do it, see my answer below.

Comment: @DarkMukke The way I'd do it is `$instance = new MyClass(['requireLogin' => true, 'baseUrl' => 'http://www.foo.bar/']);` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do this a slightly different way

in my libabry i would have
`/vendor/vendorname/pkg/config/system.php`
`/vendor/vendorname/pkg/config/local.sample.php`

and provide instructions to copy

`/vendor/vendorname/pkg/config/local.sample.php`
to
`/config/local.php`

then in my code I would have something like

```
    $sysconffile = static::$vendorbasedir . '/config/system.php';
    if (file_exists($sysconffile)) {
        $sysconf = require $sysconffile;
    } else {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Sys Conf Missing!');
    }

    $localconf = [];
    $localconfile = static::$appbasedir . '/config/local.php';
    if (file_exists($localconfile)) {
        $localconf = require $localconfile;
    }
```

UPDATE:

I also prefer static classes with data over defines, as a define is very loose in documentation, type hinting and over-writable ..

So once i have both config's, I usually do

```
static::$config = array_replace_recursive($sysconf, $localconf);
```